# Solutions for LIDAR tf Calibration

Tags: lidar, robot-calibration

I am currently engaged in a project focusing on AMR docking to a target object. The core of this process involves aligning a laser scan with a reference point cloud using the Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm. Despite efforts, the accuracy of this approach remains suboptimal, particularly as the robot moves towards the docking goal, leading me to suspect potential inaccuracies in the LIDAR's extrinsic parameters.

The current challenge lies in calibrating the LIDAR extrinsically in relation to the robot's center more precisely. While manual measurements have been our go-to method, their limitations are evident in the results we are achieving. I am keen to explore alternative calibration methods that can provide a higher degree of accuracy and reliability.

Does anyone have experience or knowledge of advanced calibration techniques or tools that could offer improvements over manual measurements?